# How to parse the error given by a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

Given this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND=$(echo test | jq)
if [[ $COMMAND == *"error"* ]]; then
        echo failed
        else
        echo success
fi
```

Since the output of `$(COMMAND)` is the following: `parse error: Invalid literal at line 2, column 0`, I'd expect to have as output of that script `failed`, but I'm having `success`.

How can I parse the error that I got on scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jq prints errors to stderr so you'd have to do this:

```
COMMAND=$(echo test | jq 2>&1)
```

But checking if command failed can be done using much easier method in
Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if ! echo test | jq '.'
then
    echo failed
else
    echo success
fi
```

Comment: ...also better to use `jq <<<"test"` and avoid a subshell just to run `echo` on the left-hand side of the pipeline in the first place.